# How to check property of function argument in NMock

Tags: .net, nmock2

Say if i had the following interface mocked in (NMock).  How could i check that email.Subject = 'xyz' ?

Currently im doing something like

```
IEmailService s = mocks.NewMock<IEmailService>();
Expect.Once.On(s).Method("Send").With(?????)

s.Send(new Email { Subject = 'rarr' });

mocks.Verify...();

interface EmailService { void SendEmail(Email email); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Has.Property` matcher](http://www.nmock.org/advanced.html) like this:

```
IEmailService s = mocks.NewMock<IEmailService>();

Expect.Once.On(s).Method("Send").
    With(Has.Property("Subject", Is.EqualTo("rarr")));

s.Send(new Email { Subject = 'rarr' });
mocks.Verify...();
```

Or you could write a custom matcher to verify that the argument is of the type `Email` and that its `Subject` property has the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check Subject inside With? That's weird to me as you are authoring unit test cases, so there is no need to validate your own test case in this way, right?

Comment: I was actually doing an integration test.  But i wanted to make sure that the object calling Send() was passing in the correct parameters.

Comment: Not sure if that's doable with NMock. Consider its own support page,

http://www.nmock.org/support.html